# How to I perform a delete request one item at a time using Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, http-delete

So, I am building a basic to-do list app using a to-do list api and I am having trouble figuring out how to delete one to-do at a time when the user clicks a delete button. I am using the id# that gets created for a new todo that is made.

I thought the code I currently have would work, but nothing happens when I click the delete button.

Any insights into what I am doing wrong?

Here's all my JavaScript, but what I am having trouble with is the last addEventListener at the bottom of the code:

```
function Todo(title, description, price){
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}

document.todo.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var titleForm = document.todo.title.value;
    var descriptionForm = document.todo.description.value;
    var priceForm = document.todo.price.value;
    var newTodo = new Todo(titleForm, descriptionForm, priceForm);

    axios.post("https://api.todo.io/name/todo", newTodo).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
})
})

axios.get("https://api.todo.io/name/todo").then(function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        var h3Price = document.createElement("h3");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var delButton = document.createElement("button");

        var displaytitle = document.createTextNode(`Title: ${response.data[i].title}`);
        var displayDescription = document.createTextNode(`Description: ${response.data[i].description}`);
        var displayPrice = document.createTextNode(`Price: ${response.data[i].price}`);
        var displayButton = document.createTextNode("Delete");

        h1.appendChild(displaytitle);
        h3.appendChild(displayDescription);
        h3Price.appendChild(displayPrice);
        delButton.appendChild(displayButton);

        div.appendChild(h1);
        div.appendChild(h3);
        div.appendChild(h3Price);
        div.appendChild(delButton);


        document.body.appendChild(div);

           delButton.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               axios.delete(`https://api.todo.io/name/todo/${response.data[i]._id}`).then(function(response){
                console.log("Todo Deleted!");
            })
           })  
        }
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: what is `delButton` ? can you add `html` part ?

Comment: `delButton` is a button element i created using JavaScript. I don't think showing the HTML would help much as I have created all the elements using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you see any error in your console ?

Comment: Nope, there's no errors.

Comment: try `delButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){`

Comment: and remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: One major problem is value of `i` when event occurs. Must read and understand [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Second major problem is a button has no `submit` event only <form> does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) for the `'submit'` event:

> Note that submit is fired **only** on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

As for your scoping problem, if you extract the body of your `for` loop as a function:

```
function addTodo({ _id, description, price, title }) {
    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    const displaytitle = document.createTextNode(`Title: ${title}`);
    h1.appendChild(displaytitle);

    const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    const displayDescription = document.createTextNode(`Description: ${description}`);
    h3.appendChild(displayDescription);

    const h3Price = document.createElement("h3");
    const displayPrice = document.createTextNode(`Price: ${price}`);
    h3Price.appendChild(displayPrice);

    const delButton = document.createElement("button");
    const displayButton = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    delButton.appendChild(displayButton);
    delButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios
          .delete(`https://api.todo.io/name/todo/${_id}`)
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Todo Deleted!");
          });
    });

    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);
    div.appendChild(h3Price);
    div.appendChild(delButton);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

axios.get("https://api.todo.io/name/todo").then(function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        addTodo(response.data[i]);
    }
    console.log(response.data);
});
```